# I went to Cabo Frio in 2020. I had never been to another state... OR I have never been to another state

Tags: american-english

Which statement is correct?

I went to Cabo Frio in 2020. I **had** never been to another state and **had** never traveled by plane.

I went to Cabo Frio in 2020. I **have** never been to another state and **have** never traveled by plane.

Comment: had is past tense, have is present tense. I cannot say if you have ever been to another state other than Rio de Janeiro to Cabo Frio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both correct, they just mean different things.

**Have** is the present tense, just like in "I have a red car right now."  *I have never been*... means that the fact is true right now.

**Had** is the past tense, just like in "I had a red car when I was 21 years old."  *I had never been*... means that the fact was true back then.

Based on your question, I am guessing that you want to use **had**: before visiting Cabo Frio, you had never been to another state and had never traveled by plane.  But now, after your visit to Cabo Frio, neither of those things is true, so you would say "I have been to another state and I have traveled by plane."